# For Riemann sums involving square roots, why do we let $c_{i} = \frac{i^{2}}{ n^{2}}$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

My Calculus book asks us to evaluate the limit:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(c_{i}) \Delta x_{i} 
$$

of f(x) = $\sqrt{x}$ within [0,3]

Why is the right endpoint given as $3\frac{i^2}{n^2}$?

Similarly, $c_{i}$ becomes $\frac{i^3}{n^3}$ for $\sqrt[3]{x}$ within [0,1].

I apologize if my LaTeX is bad, my first attempt.

It doesn't explain it very well in the book.

Thanks!

Comment: $(0+(3-0))(\frac{i}{n})^2$

Comment: Thanks Alex.  I get that, but where is the squared part coming in?  Up until this point we'd only used $\frac{i}{n}$.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the size of the mesh is, as long as it goes to $0$. Using $i^2/n^2$ simply makes calculating $f(c_i)$ a lot easier when $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$. Same deal for $f(x) = \sqrt[3]{x}$.

Comment: Thanks again, that makes sense... so what would the best way then be to handle a Riemann sum of something like f(x) = $x\sqrt{3-x}$?  Would I just plug $\frac{i}{n}$ into the original function?

Comment: For that, I would write $u = 3-x$ and then evaluate the Riemann sum over the appropriate interval for $u$. If you have an interval $[a,b]$ where $0 < a < b$ you can always evaluate two Riemann Sums: one on $[0,b]$; and the second on $[0,a]$; and then subtract the second result from the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you divide the interval $[0,3]$ into a partition where the ith interval is $$\left[3{i^2\over n^2},3{(i+1)^2\over n^2}\right]$$ then the length of that interval is $$3\frac{2i+1}{n^2}$$ So the sum becomes $$\sum{3\frac{2i+1}{n^2}\sqrt{3}\frac{i+1}{n}}=3\sqrt{3}{1\over n^3}\left(2\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+3\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+n\right)=3\sqrt{3}{2\over 3}=2\sqrt{3}$$ in the limit. The reason for the strange partition is so that taking the square root does not put square roots into the sum itself, which would greatly complicate things.